# Removing and shifting remaining elements in an array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

**List.cpp (class definitions)**

I have been working on code that is suppose to help familiarize with classes. My code currently has a function that displays a menu of options for the users. Option [1] is suppose to add a string, option [2] is suppose to remove a string from the list, option [3] prints the string list, option [4] exits. My option [1] seems to work okay as the user is able to input one string at a time but I am having a hard time with the removal of a string. The strings are currently stored in an array of 10 elements. I believe the function I wrote for the string removal is okay as I have debugged it and it seems successful, however, I am not seeing results on my console window.

My array is located in a private class in my class: string items[MAX_ITEMS]; along with another variable called: int totalItems;

The class is then called in my main function using a switch case:

```
//This code snippet below is located in a separate cpp file with main
cout << "Please enter the text you want to remove: " << endl;
cin >> userInput;
list1.remove(userInput);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//preprocessor directives
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//header files
#include "list.h"

using namespace std;

List::List()
{
    //clear array prior to starting (set everything to NULL)
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ITEMS; i++)
    {
        items[i] = " ";
    }

    totalItems = 0;
}

//void List::init()
//{
//  string items[MAX_ITEMS];
//  totalItems = 0;
//}


bool List::insert(const string& data)
{

    //verifies that string is not empty, not in the list, and not full
    if (data.empty() == true || inList(data) == true || isFull() == true)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        //      items[isFull)] = data;
        //      totalItems++;
        items[totalItems++] = data;
        return true;
    }
}


bool List::isEmpty() const
{
    //runs through loop to verify array is empty
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ITEMS; i++)
    {
        if (items[i].empty() != true)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

//identifies whether the string is full or not
bool List::isFull() const
{
    if (totalItems == MAX_ITEMS)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

//identifies whether the string is already in the list or not
bool List::inList(const string& theList)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ITEMS; i++)
    {
        if (items[i] == theList)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool List::remove(const string& data)
{
    if (inList(data) == true || data.empty() == true)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ITEMS; i++)
    {
        if (items[i] == data)
        {
            items[i] == " ";
            for (int j = i; j < MAX_ITEMS; j++)
            {
                items[j] = items[j + 1];
                items[MAX_ITEMS - 1] == " ";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    totalItems--;
    return true;
}

//prints list
void List::printList()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ITEMS; i++)
    {
        cout << i << items[i] << '\t';
    }
}
```

**list_test.cpp (main.cpp)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//header files
#include "list.h"

using namespace std;

//function prototypes
int showSelection();

int main()
{
    List list1;

    string userInput = "";
    int userChoice;

//  list1.init();

    userChoice = showSelection();

    while (userChoice != 4)
    {
        switch(userChoice)
        {
            case 1:
                cout << "Please enter the text you want to add: " << endl;
                cin >> userInput;
                list1.insert(userInput);

                /*if (list1.inList(userInput) == false)
                {
                    cout << "Text is already entered in the list!" << endl;
                }*/

                if (list1.isFull() == true)
                {
                    cout << "You have entered the MAXIMUM amount of elements!" << endl;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Please enter the text you want to remove: " << endl;
                cin >> userInput;
                list1.remove(userInput);
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "Printed list: " << endl;
                list1.printList();
                break;
        }
        userChoice = showSelection();
    }

    cout << "Goodbye. Please press enter to exit." << endl;
    //TESTING PURPOSES FOR FUNCTIONS
    cout << list1.insert(userInput) << endl;
    cout << list1.isEmpty() << endl;
    cout << list1.isFull() << endl;
    cout << list1.inList(userInput) << endl;


    return 0;
}

/* ===========================================
Name: showSelection
Desc: displays menu for user to choose options
      for their inputted string(s).
Args: none
Retn: none
=========================================== */
int showSelection() 
{
    int userChoice;
    bool exit = false;

    while (exit == false)
    {
        cout << "\nTo select an option, please enter the corresponding number: " << endl;
        cout << "[1] to add a string" << endl;
        cout << "[2] to remove a string" << endl;
        cout << "[3] to print a string" << endl;
        cout << "[4] to exit" << endl << endl;
        cin >> userChoice;

        cout << "You entered option: " << userChoice << endl;
        cout << '\n';

        if (userChoice == 1 || userChoice == 2 || userChoice == 3 || userChoice == 4)
        {
            exit = true;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid selection" << endl;
        }
    }`enter code here`
    return userChoice;
}
```

Comment: should the test inList(data) == true be inList(data) == false in remove()?

Comment: there is UB as well in nested for loop in remove function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you code should probably look:

```
bool List::remove(const string& data) {
    // only check if the list is empty so you don't nececarily go through it
    // you shoudn't ask here if the given string is in the list 
    // because you will search for it anyway just below
    if (data.empty()) 
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ITEMS; ++i) {
        if (items[i] == data) { // now if it was found
            items[i] = " "; // set it to your empty value
            --totalItems; // prefix -- is faster then postfix one (no copy is created)
            for (int j = i; j < MAX_ITEMS - 1; ++j) { 
                // stop at j < MAX_ITEMS - 1 because you wouldn't want 
                // to swap last element with the next because there 
                // is none behind it
                if (items[j + 1] == " ")
                    // if the next item is already empty you don't need to shift any more
                    return true;

                // swap the next item with much more 
                // efficient std::swap function
                std::swap(items[j], items[j + 1]);
            }
            return true; // value is removed and items shifted so you can now return
        }
    }
    // if function gets to this point that means the value wasn't found
    return false;
}
```

If you would like to make your code more efficient, I can give you more suggestions on how to do it. This above should answer your question.

Also using an array for a struct like this isn't optimal at all. Using linked listed would mean no shifting would be required.

Edit: replaced long text with a code example
Edit2: added return statement if shifting is no longer necessary

Comment: items[i] == " "; does nothing at all. Assuming you wanted items[i] = " "; .

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I really appreciate everyone's help who has contributed to this post. @Maros Betko Thank you for providing a detailed code with comments.

Comment: @KiraCorbett No problem. if you have any other questions feel free to ask. Also marking the answer as correct and upvoting will help others to find this solutions as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (inList(data) == true || data.empty() == true)
{
    return false;
}
```

If the data parameter is in your list object, you return without removing anything? this should be !inList(data)

Additionally, when you make it into the loop below this code this loop:

```
for (int j = i; j < MAX_ITEMS; j++)
{
    items[j] = items[j + 1];
    items[MAX_ITEMS - 1] == " ";
    break;
}
```

will only execute for j=i, the "break" statement will stop execution of this inner loop, and go back to the outer loop.

EDIT: this is how I personally would go about this problem.

```
bool List::remove(const string& data)
{
    bool retVal;
    if (!inList(data) || data.empty())
    {
        retVal = false;
    }
    else{
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ITEMS; i++)
        {
            if (items[i] == data)
            {
                items[i] = " ";
                for (int j = i; j < (MAX_ITEMS - 1); j++)
                {
                    items[j] = items[j + 1];
                }
                items[MAX_ITEMS-1] = " ";
            }
        }
        totalItems--; 
        retVal = true;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that. The intention for this statement is not to remove any strings yet. It is just to return false if given string is not in the list.

Comment: Right now this returns false if the given string IS in the list, so this is a logic error. inList(data) != true, inList(data) == false, or !inList(data) will all evaluate to true if the parameter data is NOT in the list object

Comment: I attempted the last code snippet and it resulted in a debug error when executed.

Comment: why do you need to create bool variable for returning value? In first if statement "== true" is redundant. In nested for loop there is undedined behaviour when you ask for items[j+1] if j == MAX_ITEMS - 1. Please don't post incorrect answers.

Comment: avoiding multiple return statements is nice, why not have a variable that is returned at the end rather then multiple returns? the "==true" is definitely redundant, but in the original code, why fix what is not broken for this guy? You are right on the last bit, but without this guys .h its not like I can actually run this code... edited

Comment: @sreichelt unnecessary allocated memory, and it doesn't make anything faster. On the contrary multiple unnecessary assigments can make it arguably slower. For me it's more readable with multiple returns.

Comment: @sreichelt It would take 2 minutes to make this code runable. Also there is nothing wrong with multiple return statements. It makes the code faster because why go through the rest of the function if everything that was required has been already done and you have the return value you want and also is much more readable for the same reason.

Comment: @MarekChocholáček this is a style choice, and the debate about multiple returns is not really in the scope of this question, personally I don't like to do it, your ability to easily read it is just as irrelevant as the size of a single bool variable in this case.

Comment: @sreichelt don't forget assigments you make. But you are right, it's style choice however bad the style may be.

Answer (score 1):

FOR me it's unclear what you want to do as unavailability of full code to run.

But I think this should work as of what I think yo want to do

```
bool List::remove(const string& data){

for (int i = 0; i < totalItems; i++)
{

    if (items[i] == data)
    {

        for (int j = i; j < totalItems-1; j++)
        {

            items[j] = items[j+1];

        }
        totalItems--;
       return true; 
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: First if statement is invalid. If data is in list you definetely don't want to return false and don't do anything. You can break after first time you encounter " " in nested for loop. You substract totalItems two times as well. This won't work properly, not even efficiently.

Comment: @MarekChocholáček My Mistake , I didnt saw whole code i just saw the core logic of shifting , LET ME EDIT

Comment: np, everybody makes mistakes. I tried to suggest edit but apparently I can't do that yet.

Comment: what does break after return do? Also indent properly please.

Comment: Here is my main.cpp which you can place in a separate .cpp file from the first code I posted. The two cpp files go hand-in-hand but you should be able to create two cpp files and execute it yourself.